# Animated GIFs in a blog?

Tags: blog

I tried adding some animated GIFs (1mb to 8mb in size) to my personal blog page on Sharepoint Online. Whilst they animated initially in the "edit mode" they fail to animate once I save the post.  Is this a known limitation or is there a workaround?

[image]

Comment: I tried on my side and working properly, could you upload one from your side to test it on my side ?

Comment: Will do on Monday.  Will also include an animated GIF of the issue into the original Q.

Comment: I noticed that the selected image size is 0 byte, try to use another image and check if you still face the same issue or not

Comment: Updated video.  Same behaviour.

Comment: Realised that this is not Sharepoint but a Delve Blog.  Therefore assume it does not belong here and should be deleted?